# Unbounded $\omega_1$-sequence in $^*\mathbb{N}$

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters, nonstandard-analysis, ultrapowers

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$. Let $^*\mathbb{N}$ = $\mathbb{N}^\omega/\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrapower. Let $\{n_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\omega_1}$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $^*\mathbb{N}$.

Assuming ZFC, would this sequence be unbounded in $^*\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $\forall n \in {^*\mathbb{N}}\  \exists \alpha \in \omega_1\ n_\alpha > n $? Does it depend on CH?

Comment: I don't think (2) will play any role (if $u$ satisfies (1), it's easy to produce $u'$ satisfying (1) and (2), and such that $u$ is bounded iff $u'$ is bounded).

Comment: The set of $n\in{^*\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{m\to\omega} n(m)/m=0$ is convex but has uncountable cofinality. So there exists $(n_\alpha)$ satisfying (1) such that each $n_\alpha$ is less than the sequence $m\mapsto m$.

Comment: The question seems to be whether every sequence is unbounded, which is purportedly negatively answered here. Isn't the question rather whether some sequence is unbounded (which would better fit the title)?

Comment: @Ycor thank you for your first note. I removed the redundant condition. But how uncountable cofinality implies the existence of strictly increasing $\omega_1$ sequence?

Comment: If $X$ is a totally ordered set of uncountable cofinality, define (with choice) by transfinite induction $x_\alpha$ as some element $>x_\beta$ for all $\beta<\alpha$, for $\alpha\in\omega_1$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand, but this claim is not true for arbitrary totally ordered uncountable set. For example, there is no strictly increasing $\omega_1$ sequence of reals.

Comment: You seem to be misreading *cofinality* as *cardinality*.

Comment: By "$X$ has uncountable cofinality" I mean "for every countable subset $Y\subset X$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $\forall y\in Y$, $y<x$".

Comment: @Ycor thank you now I see the whole point. But how to prove, that set of $n \in *\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n(m)}{m} \to 0$ has uncountable cofinality?

Comment: Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of such sequences. I guess something like $u(m)=\max_{k\le m}\lceil 2^{-k}u_k(m)\rceil$ should work.

Comment: Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of such sequences. I guess: set $u(m)=1+\max_{k\le m}\lceil 2^{-k}u_k(m)\rceil$ satisfies $u\ge 2^{-k}u_k$ for all $k$ and $u(m)=o(m)$ when $m\to\omega$, so if $v(m)=m/\sqrt{m/v(m)}$, then it should work.

Comment: @YCor, Sorry, maybe I don't understand, but I don't think this construction is working. For example, let's take $$u_n(k) = 
\begin{cases}
2^{2k},\quad k = n \\
\floor{\sqrt{k}},\quad else
\end{cases}$$
In this case, $u(m) = 1 + 2^m$, hence $u(m) \neq o(m)$.

Comment: I'm maybe too hasty. Possibly one should first replace $m\mapsto u_n(m)$ with $\min(u_n(m),m2^{-n})$.

Answer (score 4):

If HC (continuum hypothesis in French) holds, then some of those sequences are cofinal whereas some are not.

Indeed, HC implies that the corresponding ultrapower$\ ^*\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a saturated ordered field with cardinal $\omega_1$. This is the same for the field $\mathbf{No}(\omega_1)$ of surreal numbers with countable birthday. So they are isomorphic.

In $\mathbf{No}(\omega_1)$, there is a strictly increasing and cofinal embedding $x \mapsto \omega^x: \mathbf{No}(\omega_1) \rightarrow \mathbf{No}(\omega_1)^{>0}$ which satisfies in particular $\forall x,y(0\leq x<y\Longrightarrow \omega^x+1<\omega^y)$. So taking integer parts in $^*\mathbb{N}$, we obtain a cofinal order embedding $ x \mapsto \left\lfloor \omega^x \right\rfloor: \mathbf{No}(\omega_1)^{\geq 0} \longrightarrow\ ^*\mathbb{N}$.
Since there are copies of $\omega_1$ in $\mathbf{No}(\omega_1)^{\geq 0}$ which are cofinal, and others which are bounded, this yields cofinal and bounded $\omega_1$-sequences in$\ ^*\mathbb{N}$.

In ZFC, I think (but I am not sure) that it is consistent that the cofinality of$\ ^*\mathbb{N}$ be $\omega_2$, meaning that each $\omega_1$-sequence would be bounded.

Comment: What does it mean to say HC holds?

Comment: @AlexKruckman HC means CH (as in "hypothèse du continu" and probably similar things in other languages).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I didn't even realize I wrote HC, which is indeed the french acronym for the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: "each $\omega_1$-sequence is bounded" literally means that the cofinality of $^*\mathbf{N}$ is $\ge\omega_2$.

Comment: You might get information about cofinality of $^*\mathbf{N}$ from https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093635237

Comment: @YCor Thanks, I'll try to dinf out tomorrow if the cardinal $d$ they are mentionning can indeed take any value between $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.